# Is it necessary to build Rails views when using Ember.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ember.js

I'm updating a Rails app to utilize Ember.js. Those views that existed within the app prior to integrating ember still work fine, but I've also added several new views. These views have all the necessary ember parts (template, controller, etc), as well as all the Rails parts, excluding the view files.

These views work fine if the user accesses them by clicking on an internal link. However, if the user reloads the page or manually enters the URL, then I get this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /contribute
Missing template pages/contribute, application/contribute with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/sites/whistlr/app/views"
  * "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@whistlr/gems/devise-3.0.0/app/views"
```

This is clearly happening because I do not have view files. The question is, is this strictly necessary? Is there some way to tell Rails to just load up the Ember views? Ideally, I'd just delete all the old Rails view files once the conversation is complete.

Comment: Your issue is more about the routing then about the views. 

Ember Router by default put its path in URL anchor, in this fashion: `http://example.com/rails_path#/ember_path`

While Rails router works on URL `path`. 

Please share fragments of your routes.rb and App.Router so we know what the paths are.

Comment: I'm using `Whistlr.Router.reopen location: 'history'` which does away with the hashmark. Think that might be interfering with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to create individual views. The trick is to catch the exception in the application controller and then force it render the layout:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
    render "/layouts/application"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary, but you need to setup the rails `routes.rb` to have a catch all route that also renders just like your index page which displays the ember app and its html.

```
namespace :api do
  # resources go here
end

root :to 'home#index'
match "/*path" => 'home#index'
```

Note: You want to customize this path pattern to your project, else 404s would also be send here.

Comment: This works great, though only when I don't need data via a Rails controller. For instance, if I go to "/organizations", the Rails controller would typically send @organizations via json. With this approach, I'm not getting the json, presumably because the rails route isn't pointing to the rails organizations controller. Maybe there's something else I'm missing?

Comment: Right, you still need to define your `resources` before this. For instance using an `/api` namespace. See my edit.

Comment: In the case of resources then, it seems that it will still be necessary to create a Rails view?

Comment: Unless you are rendering json inside a view, No. `render :json` doesn't need a view.

Comment: This issue appears when the user reloads the page/arrives at the page via an external link. At those points, I'm rendering html just to get the header in. Ember is capable of filling in the body. The thing is, even though my `application.html` page doesn't have a `yield` tag, Rails is still acting like I need a view for those pages. There has got to be a way to tell Rails not to look for the view.